# Why is '&' operator not working in RcppArmadillo

Tags: rcpp, rcpparmadillo

I am trying to obtain a logical vector from two other logical vectors connected through elementwise '&':

```
//[[Rcpp::export]]
arma::uvec test1(arma::vec t1, double R1, double R2){
arma::uvec t = (t1 >= R1) & (t1 < R2);
return t;
}
```

It returns the following error while I try to compile

```
error: no match for 'operator&' (operand types are 'arma::enable_if2<true, const arma::mtOp<unsigned int, arma::Col<double>, arma::op_rel_gteq_post> >::result {aka const arma::mtOp<unsigned int, arma::Col<double>, arma::op_rel_gteq_post>}' and 'arma::enable_if2<true, const arma::mtOp<unsigned int, arma::Col<double>, arma::op_rel_lt_post> >::result {aka const arma::mtOp<unsigned int, arma::Col<double>, arma::op_rel_lt_post>}')
arma::uvec t = (t1 >= R1) & (t1 < R2);
                          ^
```

I have no idea what was going on. I am guessing that Armadillo does things differently. But I can't find any sources to help me clear things out. Any help would be appreciated! Thank you very much!

Comment: Did you mean `&&` instead of `&` ?  The operators `&&` and `&` have completely different meaning, even if they look related. `&&` means "logical and". `&` means "bitwise and". Try changing your code to: `arma::uvec t = (t1 >= R1) && (t1 < R2);`

Comment: && does work but it doesn't give me the right answer. I need the elementwise &. && seems to just go through the shortcut option.

Comment: @davidolohowski What does elementwise mean when your comparisons are doubles?

Comment: @duckmayr Sorry I wasn't clear enough. I want the result to be a vector of true or false. But && only gives me one single true or false answer which is not something I want. But weird thing is && has no compiling issue while & does.

Comment: @davidolohowski See the updates to my answer -- I think it should work how you want it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have no idea what was going on. I am guessing that Armadillo does things differently. But I can't find any sources to help me clear things out.

The ultimate source here is [the Armadillo docs](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html). If you go down to [the section on operators](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#operators), you'll see that the `&` operator is not one of those listed among the "[o]verloaded operators for *Mat, Col, Row* and *Cube* classes." So, if you want such an operator you'll have to code it up yourself (or see if someone else already has it floating around the internet). There is such an operator for `Rcpp::NumericVector`s:

```cpp
#include <Rcpp.h>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::LogicalVector test1(const Rcpp::NumericVector& t1, double R1, double R2){
    return (t1 >= R1) & (t1 < R2);
}
```

```r
test1(1:10, 3, 7)
# [1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
# [9] FALSE FALSE
```

Of course, that doesn't help much if the rest of your code really relies on Armadillo.

## Update: Just Use `&&`

As pointed out by [mtall](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1080929/mtall) in the comments, the `&&` operator actually **is** available, even though it's not discussed in the Armadillo docs (maybe it's not as ultimate of a source as I thought).

So, just change your code to the following:

```cpp
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

//[[Rcpp::export]]
arma::uvec test1(arma::vec t1, double R1, double R2){
    arma::uvec t = (t1 >= R1) && (t1 < R2);
    return t;
}
```

and it works how I believe you want it to based on your question and response to comments:

```r
test1(1:10, 3, 7)
      [,1]
 [1,]    0
 [2,]    0
 [3,]    1
 [4,]    1
 [5,]    1
 [6,]    1
 [7,]    0
 [8,]    0
 [9,]    0
[10,]    0
```

Comment: Perhaps there is a confusion between `&&` and `&` ?

Comment: @mtall I believe so; that was my first thought, and I should have just tried the switch as you suggest in the comments. However, like a sucker I looked at the docs first and didn't see that operator listed. Having tried it, I see it works. I wonder why the `&&` operator is not listed in the docs?

Comment: @mtall Would you prefer to add your own answer re: this issue? If not, I'll update mine to include your suggestion.

Comment: @duckmayr Thanks, it did work. It was in fact my own mistake. I took it for granted since R produce one single valued bool answer if && is used. It was actually some other parts of my code had a bug that caused the problem. Apologies.